# I'm not finding anyone in the keywarden matching option

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm trying to create the new hellfire ring for lvl 70 characters. I tried to find friends playing Diablo 3 with the matchmaking service.

I selected keywarden in the options, but the result is that I often see 0 people in Torment. I need those ring so i can get 45% experience bonus.

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I don't know anything about D3, but do any other matchmaking options work? If not, it may be something about the way you're connecting (or not connecting) to the service.

Comment: I would guess because the rewards you receive, the Hellfire Amulet and Ring, aren't very good in any sense.  The Amulet, especially, is a massive crapshoot.  People probably focus on guaranteed progression, rather than taking the risk of wasting their time for farming keys and organs.

Comment: I wonder if people are still playing diablo 3 at all

Comment: Most people are probably doing rifts these days.

Comment: how else I can get 45% bonus experience then?

Comment: @JimThio People are probably relying more on communities, than matchmaking. Try **Master List** or **Achievement Hunters** (titles may vary, but similar communities exist on all realms). I've spent quite some very productive hours on EU there, both providing and receiving help.

Answer (score 3):

Diablo 3 matches players in regards to three differant groupings:

- What act you are on
- What mode you are on
- What difficulty you are on

Most people are going to aim for a higher difficulty which yields higher increase in XP, gold, and often magical drop chance. Your best bet is to move through the different difficulties until you find players.

I have had battle.net return no match only to hit enter immediately after, to be put into a game with three people.

Diablo 3 will actually return a message when you look for a game if there is any issue with connecting to Battle.net in the first place.